# XCUIElementQuery.matching(identifier:) is not working for UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift4, xctestcase, xcuitest

I'm trying to implement a very simple test, but I'm stuck with [XCUIElementQuery.matching(identifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500679-matching) method. I think querying `UIImageView`s is not working as expected, but not sure why.

I have these two settings set for views:

1. Label:[image: Label with Accessibility enabled with id: 'label']
2. UIImageView:[image: UIImageView with Accessibility enabled with id: 'accept']

And I have this test:

```
func testRecording() {
    XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts.matching(identifier: "label").count, 2)
    XCTAssertEqual(app.images.matching(identifier: "accept").count, 1)
}
```

where I'm querying for these two views (Label with id `label` and UIImageView with id `accept`). From here: `app` is simply defined as class property like this: `let app = XCUIApplication()`.

So, this is what screen looks like:
[image: Table with 2 items]

This means that this test should pass since there are two `staticText`s with id `label` and one `image` with id `accept` on screen. `staticText`s are being successfully queried, but it is failing when `matching(identifier:)` tries to query `image` with id `accept`:
[image: Test failing on image with id 'accept']

I tried to query with many things, like:

- `app.images.`
- `app.tables.`
- `app.tables.images.`
- `app.tables.cells.images.`
- `app.buttons.` (also marked as `Button` in Traits part of the Accessibility settings)
- `app.staticTexts.` (also marked as `Static Text` in Traits part of the Accessibility settings)

but no luck... Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here, or missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since I'm in the QA team, I haven't looked much to the dev code. But when I did, I found the answer.

UIImageView that is used for displaying check mark is never being used from .xib file, but instead is always allocated a new instance like this:

```
indicatorView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_marked_ok_small"))
```

meaning that new accessibility options are set with initializer call, so that old UIImageView instance that has accessibility options from .xib file I posted in first two images is being overridden.